# Redux-Saga ES6 class syntax methods do not get called on dispatch of action

Tags: redux, generator, redux-saga, es6-class

Using redux saga have implemented all methods in a class as static methods
below is the code.

Registers the rootSaga static method also when the action FETCH_POST is dispatched it never executes the fetchAuthorSaga so the call to the web api never happens but instead it goes to the reducer where the type when checked shows FETCH_POST with no data. what am i missing here ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`() => SagaAuthor.fetchAuthorSaga` is a "noop". You are passing a function that returns generator but it has to be a generator itself.

It should be `takeEvery('FETCH_POST', SagaAuthor.fetchAuthorSaga)`

[Docs](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#takeeverypattern-saga-args)

> `takeEvery(pattern, saga, ...args)` ... `saga: Function` - a Generator
>   function

And you need to do the following in `rootSaga`

```
yield all([
   call(SagaAuthor.onBootstrap) // should be effect 
])
```

Also "have implemented all methods in a class as static methods" this approach makes little sense. Why do you need a class that has no instances? Just use object literal or a module itself.

Comment: I get this error now when i change to the above code
[ts] Argument of type '"FETCH_POST"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Channel<string>'.

Comment: @user581157 I not that fluent with typescript. Esp when it comes to generators etc.

Comment: @user581157 This might help https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/1044#issuecomment-312509142